# Input type=text value null

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help me
i have 1 form with 2 input type="text" and 1 button submit

```
function Test(){
 var valid=true; 
 $('input:text').css('border-color','#e0e0e0');
var inputs=$('input:text');
for(i=0;i<inputs.length;++i)
{
    if(inputs.val()=='')
    {
        $('input:text').css('border-color','red');
        $('input:text').css('box-shadow','0 0 10px red');
        valid=false;
    }
}
return valid;
```

}

i can't alert(inputs.val())
i don't want use ID of input because i have done!

sorry because my english is very poor

Comment: Try `if(inputs[i].value=='')`

Comment: tks u so muchit worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** method to iterate all input items

```
function Test() {
    var valid = true,
            inputs = $('input:text');
    inputs.css('border-color', '#e0e0e0');
    inputs.each(function() {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
            $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 10px red');
            valid = false;
        }
    });
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop through the inputs collection but fail to use the input at index `i`. To do this use the `.eq(i)` try this:

```
var inputs=$('input:text');
for(i=0;i<inputs.length;++i)
{
    var $iEl = $inputs.eq(i);
    if($iEl.val() =='')
    {
        $iEl.css('border-color','red');
        $iEl.css('box-shadow','0 0 10px red');
        valid=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if(inputs.val()=='')
```

with

```
if(inputs[i].value=='')
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all so much
it worked!!!

but i have textarea, how to get value textarea

```
<input name="A" class="required" type="text" />
<input name="B" class="required" type="text" />
<textarea name="C" class="required" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
```

use class="required" for all
help me!